# Azure DevOps create custom calculated fields on work items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-boards

We are currently exporting queries in ADO to a csv, then copy/pasting it in our own excel file. We have a column that calculates the expected completion date via a formula made by our manager. I have been looking into if this is possible directly in ADO. I have looked into creating our own extension but haven't been able to get the data from the query fields. Is there an easier way to do this I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Azure DevOps does not support calculated fields. But you can use external services to automate your calculation. Here is the example: [Using Microsoft Flow (Power Automate) to calculate values for fields in Azure DevOps](https://dombat.co.uk/using-microsoft-flow-to-fill-calculated-fields-in-azure-devops/)